# Intel HAXM installation error

Tags: android

I am not able to install Intel(R) Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM) in my lenovo Thinkpad E520 having Intel® Core™ i3-2330M Processor  (3M Cache, 2.20 GHz) Processor with 4 GB RAM.

As it give the following error " This computer meets the requirement of HAXM. But Intel Virulization Technology VT-X is not turned on. HAXM cannot be installed untill VT-X is enabled. Please refer to the intel HAXM documentation for more information".

I have already been enabled the  VT-D in BIOS. but still the same error. Kindly guide me how i may fix that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this steps:

- Open *Control Panel*
- Open *Programs and Features*.
- Click on *Turn Windows features on and off*.
- Uncheck *Hyper-V* option and restart your computer.

After that you should be able to install HAXM.

**Edit** On this [troubleshooting](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/03/14/troubleshooting-intel-haxm) page, Intel suggest also this:

- Make sure the Execute Disable bit is enabled (and supported). You can run the following command as administrator: >**bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn**
- Do you have anything else running on your system that uses VT? (Like VirtualBox?) Same issue as with Hyper-V.

Answer (score 0):

There's a command to turn hypervisor off without entering control panel
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off.   
Some other things -
    Turn off antivirus  - especially Avast (Avast:  disable "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization" under: Settings > Troubleshooting) 

 Then reboot and 

 Download the separate installer rather than install thru Android studio
https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager